# VideoView giving FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to learn how to use VideoView in Android Studio to play videos and on running the app i keep getting "Can't Play this Video". Logcat shows a File Not found exception. Also, when i try opening the file in Android Studio it says file is not associated with any file type.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        String uriPath = "android:resources://" + getPackageName() + "/res/raw.demovideo";

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.start();
```

[image: Image of my Project Structure showing the Video file]

Comment: Try `/res/raw/demovideo`, not `/res/raw.demovideo`.

Comment: Tried still the same Error